# How to select parent checkbox based on child checkboxes in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I've been playing with Angular.js recently and decided to check all the checkboxes once parent checkbox is checked, which I've done using `ng-model` and `ng-checked` directives.

```
    <div ng-app>
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="parent"/> Select All<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="child_1" ng-checked="parent" ng-click="getAllSelected()"/> First<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="child_2" ng-checked="parent" ng-click="getAllSelected()"/> Second<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="child_3" ng-checked="parent" ng-click="getAllSelected()"/> Three<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="child_4" ng-checked="parent" ng-click="getAllSelected()"/> Four<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="child_5" ng-checked="parent" ng-click="getAllSelected()"/> Five<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I'm trying select all the parent checkbox once all the child checkboxes are checked but facing some issues.

```
    function Ctrl($scope) {
       $scope.getAllSelected = function () {
          var chkChild = document.querySelectorAll('input[ng-model^="child_"]').length;
          var chkChildChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input[ng-model^="child_"]:checked').length;
          if (chkChild === chkChildChecked) $scope.parent= true;
          else $scope.parent= false;
       }
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/QekpX/

Can we make the above code more robust?

Comment: What do you expect to happen once you uncheck any of the checkboxes?

Comment: I've added the demo link above. Once I check the parent checkbox, it checks all the child checkboxes. But when I uncheck one of the checked child checkboxes, it should uncheck the parent one too.

Comment: Like all the checkboxes should be in sync?

Comment: You can map multiple elements to a single model, then they would be in sync.(`ng-model="parent"` to all checkboxes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ng-checked attribute in the checkbox takes in an expression. So you can give an expression with and/or conditions, as mentioned below to make it checked based on an expression.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="child_1 && child_2 && child_3 && child_4 && child_5" ng-model="parent"/> Select All<br/>
```

You dont have to write a seprate function to do the computation when every child checkbox is clicked.

[Here is example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pio123/624y6/1/)

Comment: In the official documentation you can see that angular advises not use ng-checked with ng-model together https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Comment: I'm sorry to dig up this topic, but is there a dynamic solution to solve the same problem. The difference is that I don't know exactly the number of childrens... @manoj

Answer (score 0):

Visually it updates all the checkboxes checked with ng-selected, but then when you go to actually submit the data the data doesn't match up with what was selected.  I suggest doing a ng-click() which sucks, but if your data is dynamic.

http://codepen.io/stirlingw/pen/gpwXWM

```
//Random JSON object
$scope.labels = 
  [{
    label: 'Death Row Records', 
    selected: false, 
    artists: [
      {artist: 'MC Hammer', selected: false},
      {artist: 'Andre "Dr. Dre" Young', selected: false},
      {artist: 'Snoop Dogg', selected: false},
      {artist: 'Tupac Shakur', selected: false},
      {artist: 'Nate Dogg', selected: false},
   ]
}]; 

//JS
$scope.clicker = function(label){
  label.artists.forEach(function(e){
    e.selected = !label.selected;
  });
};

//html
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="label in labels"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="label.selected" ng-click="clicker(label)"> {{label.label}} 
       <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="artist in label.artists">
               <input type="checkbox" ng-model="artist.selected" > {{artist.artist}}
           </li>
       </ul> 
   </li>  
</ul>
```