# Set Model is Null in Directive in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to set modelvalue Null in directive, on changing checkbox checked or unchecked.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isCheck"  />
    <select ng-model="empNmae" ng-setempty="isCheck" 
    ng-options="em.Value as em.Name for em in emp">
      <option value="">Select
    </select>
    {{empNmae}}
```

JS

```
// Code goes here
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("mycntrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.emp=[{
  "Name":"Amit",
  "Value":101
},{
  "Name":"Amit2",
  "Value":103
},{
  "Name":"Amit3",
  "Value":102
}];
$scope.empNmae=102;
$scope.isCheck=true;
});

app.directive('ngSetempty', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function (scope,element, attrs, ctrl) {
         scope.$watch(attrs.ngSetempty, function () {
                var getChekc=this.last;
                if(getChekc){
                 // set Model is NULL
                }
            });

        }
    };
});
```

if checkbox is checked , Then I want to set the model is Null for selectbox.
**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o5r4m7H6VztCvoXW3rZv?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a simple :

```
delete $scope.empNmae
```

?

Comment: But how would I know the  "empNmae" . It will be different for different control,, as i'll use this directive on multiple control.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-checked=myFunction()` attribute to your checkbox and clear the model in `myFunction()`.

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="empNmae" ng-setempty="isCheck" 
    ng-options="em.Value as em.Name for em in emp" ng-checked="clearModel()">
```

JS:

```
$scope.clearModel = function(){
    $scope.empNmae = null;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873170/586051).

[Angular ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).