# Checking the number of rows that are checked in an AngularJS grid

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can I check if any rows have been selected via a checkbox in an AngularJS grid in order to display a button and vice-versa?

Comment: are you talking about the UI-Grid directives or just in general have a grid with checkboxes and check if some have been selected?

Comment: the latter.... I also don't have any checkboxes currently on the grid and would like to know a simple code snippet on adding a checkbox for each row.

Comment: so your asking how to create a table with checkboxes on its side and how to know when the checkboxes have been checked?

Comment: Exactly.... Once I know it's checked, I need to get cell information from that row.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872832/how-to-respond-to-clicks-on-a-checkbox-in-an-angularjs-directive if that doesnt help you Ill give you a small code example